# Is there a way to get a Rally Custom report Chart and attach it to a html file?

Tags: html, api, rally

I am trying to create an HTML file with the data from the rally. I want to show a custom chart(defect) on HTML file. How do I do this?
I am using an HTMLViewer toolkit to create HTML file and really-rest-API for fetching rally data

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Export the chart?

Comment: I want to build a chart/table with query and then export these charts to send an email